# Whenever i click just outside any button(which is UISegmentedControl button) also, the button gets clicked. Can anyone tell me why is this happening?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uibutton

[image]In my project, i am having a problem with clicking of the button which i have set as segmentedControl. When tapped just outside the button also, the button gets clicked. Can anyone give a solution to this?

Comment: Please post some code and a photo of your button.

Comment: can you show us images of your storyBoard or xib

Comment: If you are using a button background image, then frame of that button may be larger than image size(In Case of programmatically created button)

Comment: yes, i am using background image for the button. I have kept the same width and height of the button as its image size but still it has problem. :(

Comment: Do you creating the button programmatically? If so,Can you show the code where you are creating and setting the button image?

Comment: Actualy i am really sorry, i haven't used backgroundImage for the button. Its just that i have made the button UISegmentedControl

Comment: Is your segmented control inside of a navigation bar or tool bar? What view are you adding it to?

Comment: yes, i am using the segmentedControl inside the navigationBar.

Comment: That explains it. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the button is inside a navigation bar, then the behavior is normal as far as I can tell. I've noticed the same behavior with regular bar button items. Drag and drop a bar button item into a navigation bar, run the app in the simulator. You'll notice that your mouse cursor can be just outside the button boundary and still activate the button. So what's going on? I think the system (the navigation bar) it just trying to predict what our fat hominid fingers are trying to touch.

Comment: so nothing can be done in that case right? It has to be that way only as it is now?

Comment: Hey thanx a lot for the help. You were right. I checked it by dragging the barButton to the navigationBar and the same thing happened. Thank You ver much. :)

Answer (score 1):

Probably you have bind (programmatically or via IB) your action to wrong button's

```
UIControlEvents
```

value. It should be

```
UIControlEventTouchUpInside
```

If you have created UIButoon programmatically check that you have

```
[button addTarget:target action:selector forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: I am using a segmentedControl for the button. In the sense, i have made the button UISegmentedControl